# Can't find my custom attribute in product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-collection

In catalog/category/product in

`foreach ($_productCollection as $_product)`

I want to getMy attribute to do some condition but it doesnt work

```
<?php

if ($_product->getPromo()) {
    echo 'Ok';
}
?>
```

instead to do my own collection with the `->AddAttributeToFilter('Promo', 1)` to avoid another foreach

Comment: You need to filter the default category product colletion with your custom attribute "promo", right?

Comment: No, i want to add an attribute to collection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all check that are you getting your attribute in product collection data using `print_r($_product->getData())`.

If it is not there in product data check your attribute is properly created or not.

Else, sometimes it happens that you need to load the product model again with product id in for loop. Like ..

```
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) {
  $loadProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId());
  $promo = $loadProd->getPromo(); //or your attribute name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Else, sometimes it happens that you need to load the product model again with product id in for loop. Like ..

No. Never ever you **need** to load the product model again! This is a first good step to max. page load times ...

`addAttributeToFilter('Promo', 1)` will apply i filter on your collection, but it will not add the attribute to select statement. To add custom attributes, try this

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('promo')
```

Comment: How you found this question @sv3n ? I completely forgot it, You are going to browse all my questions lol :) I agree with you it is not a good practice to do a load in a foreach but I have not used this solution. The solution that i used is to set my attribute used in product list to yes and the problem is solved

Comment: @Prince yep :P , because you asked some good questions :) But this answer ... erm no, this should not be the only answer if someone else finds this :) This is bad**est** practice in my opinion.

Comment: Yes sure it's not at all the best practice. I dont used it

Comment: Nope :) Maybe tomorrow ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63520/discussion-between-prince-and-sv3n).